# stacked barplot returning individual bars

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am attempting to make a stacked bar plot and it is simply not working. I have attached my data and the script I have tried. My data is tab delimited and only has 4 rows of data. Color is suppose to be a method by which I can color my bar graph.

```
Person   Count   Color
Jim   35   Y
Jim   10   N
Jenny   12   Y
Jenny   25   N
```

So what I am expecting is Jim's bars to stack on top of each other and have Jenny's next his stacked as well. But that is not what is occuring, the bars are present but they are besides each other despite belonging to the same person.

Code I have tried

```
barplot(count, col = color) ##this will get me the unstacked bars


###what I have seen as examples but I already have a table...
count = table (person, count)
count
barplot(count, col = color)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The barplot function (from the graphics package) requires either a vector or matrix of values describing the bars which make up the plot. Not a data frame. So, if your data is structure like this:

```
> X <- matrix(c(12,25,35,10), nr=2)
> dimnames(X) <- list(Color=c("Y","N"), Person=c("Jenny","Jim"))
> X
     Person
Color Jenny Jim
    Y    12  35
    N    25  10
```

Which is a 2x2 table of counts, then you can plot that easily:

```
> barplot(X)
```

Of course R usually gives minimal output, including graphs, so to make it look more presentable, you'll need to add some arguments.

```
op <- par(mar=par("mar") + c(0,0,0,1)) # add some space for the legend on the right, saving the original pars
barplot(X, xlab="Person", ylab="Count", # add axis labels
        las=1, # make tick labels horizontal
        col=c("turquoise2","tomato"), border="white", # change colors
        legend=TRUE, # add a legend with some parameters...
        args.legend=list(x="right", title="Color", bt="n", border="white", inset=-0.2)
        )
par(op) # restore original graphical parameters
```

[image]

The result is similar to the default graph produced by ggplot, which requires a data frame, not a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As @Edward correctly mentioned, you need a table, not data.frame. Just in case you need it (and for fun), you can use dplyr to cast it into a matrix and plot:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(values_from=Count,names_from=Person) %>% tibble::column_to_rownames("Color") %>% 
{barplot(as.matrix(.),col=c("turquoise","orange"))}
```

[image]